# Каким правилом надо пользоваться, чтобы избежать ошибок в суффиксах фамилий?

Tags: орфография, ономастика

В учебнике Русский язык за 5 кл. ч. 1 Ладыженской упр. 308 прописана фамилия КАЛАНЧОВ (суф. ОВ, а не ЕВ). Это ошибка в учебнике, так как в именах собственных пишем: Хрущев, Горбачев, Сычев. Каким правилом надо пользоваться?

Answer (score 2):

Да, действительно, есть такое упражнение (здесь — [298](https://porusskomu.ru/5-klass/gdz-uchebnik-ladyzhenskaya-t.a.-baranov-m.d.-trostencova-l.a.-5-klass-1-chast/58.-alfavit.html)):
Представьте, что в вашем классе 10 учеников, у которых фамилии начинаются на букву "К": Качкин, **Каланчов**, Карачинцев, Куняев, Кутепов, Квасцов, Карпинский, Кошкин, Котеночкин, Кулагин. Составьте алфавитный список этих учеников. Как вы поступите в тех случаях, когда первые буквы или первые и вторые буквы в фамилиях совпадают? Какой частью речи являются записанные слова?

Есть и правило в ПАС под редакцией Лопатина ([Гласные после шипящих и ***ц***, § 18](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=14#pp14)):

> Примечание 2. В русских фамилиях на шипящий *+ -ов (-ёв)* пишется ***о*** или ***ё*** в соответствии с традицией и с регистрацией в официальных документах: ср., например, *Чернышов* и *Чернышёв*, *Калачов* и *Калачёв*, *Хрущов* и *Хрущёв*; *Емельян Пугачёв*.

У Розенталя ([Буквы ***о*** и ***е*** после шипящих](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=36#pp36)):

> **Примечание.** Правило не распространяется на написание имен собственных: *Пугачёв, Ткачов, Ширшов, Чернышёв* и т. п.

Еще примеры: Борщов и Борщёв, Мохначов и Мохначёв, Толмачов и Толмачёв.
И вот, думаю, интересная статья: [Вновь о букве Ё](https://pravoslavie.ru/36346.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Каким правилом надо пользоваться?

См. **ПАС:**

> **§ 18**. После ***ж, ч, ш, щ*** для передачи ударного гласного ***о*** пишется буква ***о*** или ***ё***.
>
> <…>
>
> Примечание 2. В русских фамилиях на шипящий + -*ов* (-*ёв*) пишется
> ***о*** или ***ё* в соответствии с традицией и с регистрацией в официальных документах**: ср., например, *Чернышов* и *Чернышёв,
> Калачов* и *Калачёв, Хрущов* и *Хрущёв; Емельян Пугачёв.*

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=18#pp18

Answer (score 0):

Никаким правилом не пользуемся. Ибо такового не существует.

В фамилиях сохраняется та же гласная (о/ё, и/ы), что указана в документе носителя. Свидетельстве о рождение, о крещении, записи в загсе, в паспорте.